# How to clear text field before sending new text values in Serenity

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

```
 @When("{actor} adds/edits (new )user in (his) contact list")
public void contact_add_new_user_in_contact_list(Actor actor, DataTable dataTable) {
    Map<String, String> data = dataTable.asMaps().get(0);
    actor.attemptsTo(AddContacts.fromDte(data.get("FirstName"), data.get("LastName"),
            data.get("Email"), data.get("Phone")));
    actor.attemptsTo(Click.on(ContactModal.SAVE_BUTTON.waitingForNoMoreThan(
            Duration.ofSeconds(10))));
}
```

So Here I want to clear previously present data in the form field before sending new values.

Answer (score 0):

try this _actor.AttemptsTo(Clear.On(FormFieldLocator.locatorObject));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).